# Dynamic pages using FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a link on a page which generates a pdf. I am using fpdf for the same. My requirement is that we have to generate a single pdf with different pages each having footer and header.

E.g. a students makes a payment through cash, cheques. I have to generate a pdf displaying payment mode , amount etc. I am running a loop for each instrument type but the issue is that the pdf shows one entry only because i think it is being overwritten. I have tried page break but with now success.

Code

```
require_once(APP_PHYSICAL_PATH."libs/fpdf/fpdf.php");

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    function Header()
    {
        $this->Image(APP_WEBROOT_PHYSICAL_PATH.'app_images/site-logo.gif',10,8,33);
        $this->Ln(15);

        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
        $this->MultiCell(0,0,'mysite.',0,'C');
        $this->Ln(5);

        $this->SetFont('Arial','',10);
        $this->MultiCell(0,0,'67, addd2',0,'C');
        $this->Ln(5);

        $this->MultiCell(0,0,'Tel No - 010000000, Website:www.site.com',0,'C');
        $this->Ln(10);
    }

    function Footer()
    {
        $this->Ln(10);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
        $this->MultiCell(0,0,'For mycomany.',0,'R');
        $this->Ln(20);
        $this->MultiCell(0,0,'Center Manager',0,'R');
    }

}
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{ 
$pdf = new PDF();

$pdf->AddPage('P','Letter');
$pdf->SetAuthor("MYCompany");
$pdf->SetCreator("MYCompany");
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, 'Acknowledgement', 0, 'C');
$pdf->Ln(10);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,0,"Date: ".$details[0]['datepaid'],0,'L');
$pdf->MultiCell(0,0, "Acknowledgement No : ".date('Y/m/d')."/".$details[0]['pk_paymentid'],0,'R');
$pdf->Ln(10);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, "We acknowledge receipt of Rs ".$details[0]['amountpaid']." from Ms/Mr ".$details[0]['fullname'], 0, 'J');
$pdf->Ln(5);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,'Course Name',1,0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,$details[0]['name'],1,0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(7);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,'Course Fee (Total)','LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,round($courseData[0]['courseFee']),'LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(7);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,"Service Tax",'LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,round($courseData[0]['serviceTax']),'LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(7);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,'Total Amount Payable','LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,round($courseData[0]['totalAmount']),'LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(7);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,'Amount Received','LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,round($details[0]['amountpaid']),'LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(7);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,'Balance Amount Payable','LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$balance=round($courseData[0]['totalAmount']-$details[0]['amountpaid']);
if($balance<1)
{
$balance=0;
}
 $pdf->Cell(90,7,$balance,'LBR',0,'L');
// $pdf->Cell(90,7,$courseData[0]['totalAmount']-$details[0]['amountpaid'],'LBR',0,'L');
 $pdf->Ln(7);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,'Mode of Payment','LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,"",'LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(7);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,'Cheque/Demand Draft/Credit Card Number','LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,"",'LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(7);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,'Name of Bank and Branch','LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->Cell(90,7,"",'LBR',0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(20);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','I',10);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,0,'* Service Tax Regn No _____________',0,'L');
$pdf->Ln(10);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, 'For further processing of your registeration to the above program, we are forwarding your details to our enrollment center at', 0, 'L');
$pdf->Ln(5);
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 0, 'Centre. For all queries please contact:', 0, 'L');
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->MultiCell(0,0,'myaddress',0,'L');
}
//$pdf->Output();
$pdf->Output('Enrolment_No_'.$details[0]['enrolmentid'].".pdf",'D');
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: So what exactly is your problem? You speak of a loop, but in your code there's no loop, so it seems quite normal to me you only get one entry.

Comment: @wimvds i have removed the loop which i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: So how do you expect us to find your error if you removed the relevant code?

Comment: @wimvds i have edited the question and added the loop now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so now your error is quite obvious. You have to put the `$pdf = new PDF();` before your loop.

ie.

```
$pdf = new PDF();
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++)
{ 
    $pdf->AddPage('P','Letter');
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a close look at fpdi & tcpdf.
The best way to read an extending pdf is that way:

```
class PDF extends FPDI { 
    var $_tplIdx;
    function Header() {}    
    function Footer() {}        
}

$pdf = new PDF();
$tpages = $pdf->setSourceFile("yourpdf.pdf");
/**
* Set a source-file
*
* @param string $filename a valid filename
* @return int number of available pages
*/
```

,... then simply loop the pages and you're done :)

Comment: In order be able to run my sample you need:
fpdi:
[link](http://www.tcpdf.org/)

And:
tcpdf with tpl:
[link](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/downloads/)